# How to Change the default Application image in android?

Tags: android, image, icons

How to Change the  default Application image in android??we want to distinguish our application to other android application.so we i want to change the default android application image to sepate image.

how this can be done?anyone pls help me?

Comment: Have you spent any time at all reading the documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put an image in your project and reference it in your `androidmanifest.xml` file with

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

in the `<application>` part

Random reference with a tiny bit more detail: http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=97

(a bit offtopic, but this is a great page from the dev-guide for making icons: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html )